# Can not see the static data after navigating from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, text, static

I have three activities. In first I am calling second activity from text view of from and to location. From second activity I am calling third activity which stores location. I want to show this location in first activity's text view.
I am getting the locations on text views but after selecting from location when I am selecting to location the text of from location disappears. I am storing this data in singleton class.
Unable to get the error..

GoSend Activity(first activity)

```
public void setAddress()
{

   if(GoSendData.instance.addressType==0) {
        txt_from.setText(GoSendData.instance.getmFromLocation());
    }
    else if(GoSendData.instance.addressType==1)
    {
        txt_to.setText(GoSendData.instance.getmToLocation());
    }

}
```

ChooseFromMapActivity(third activity)

```
private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // boolean duplicateResponse;


    public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        x = latitude;
        y = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            geocoder = new Geocoder(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
            str = new StringBuilder();
            if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {

                if ((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() > 0)) {
                    Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                    String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                    String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                    String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                    String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                    str.append(localityString + "");
                    str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                    str.append(zipcode + "");



                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        String fromLocation,toLocation;
        try {
            Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
          //  address=(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
               //     + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");

            if (GoSendData.instance.addressType==0) {
                address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";
                GoSendData.instance.setmFromLocation(address);
            }

            else
            {
                address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";
                GoSendData.instance.setmToLocation(address);
            }
          //  toLocation=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)+"";
            //GoSendData.instance.setmToLocation(toLocation);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}
```

Comment: onActivityResult() in first and second activity

Comment: but i am not calling third activity directly. I have second activity in between.@ Rah

Comment: hi can you post your three class completely.so that i can check it.why in third.activity why you are passing  return null;

Comment: you can use sharedPreference() or Application Class

Answer (score 1):

It seems the data you set is empty. But I may be wrong. I recommend you to log each step. You can use the Log class. Especially check the value of the "address" string.

Comment: I am setting the data in GoSendData onPost execute method.

Comment: Then please post your question properly. How can we help you if we don't know what you are doing?

Comment: See the updated answer. You should check the values and print them out. Then you will maybe see what is going on.

Comment: address is not null. I get the address in both but the problem is after setting from location when i go to the third activity to set to location to location is also set but can not view the from location. its gone.

Comment: So you are getting the address when you call GoSendData.instance.getmFromLocation() and GoSendData.instance.getmToLocation()?

Comment: yes i am getting the address.. but when i get the toLocation address . From location address is not seen. in the from location text view of GoSendData activity..@longwalker

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am passing data from third activity to the first activity. Hope this will help you.

In `MainActivity.java`

```
private static final int REQ_CODE = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), REQ_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            String text = data.getStringExtra("text");
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In `SecondActivity.java`

```
private static final int REQ_CODE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class), REQ_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

In `ThirdActivity.java`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("text", "Passing data between activities.");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        this.finish();
    }
```

Comment: It dose not start third activity.. I want to choose location on third activity then send it to first activity on click of button. @Faraz Hussain